# Graph API expired subscription can still be retrieved from the list of subscription

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

I suppose the list of subscription using "GET /subscriptions" should only show active subscriptions i.e. not including the ones that has expired.

However, I am facing issue for one of the tenant where the expired subscriptions are part of the subscription list. Below is the list of subscription that I just retrieved and all of them has expired:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#subscriptions",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "45a12267-662d-4997-a5b2-...",
            "resource": "/teams/getAllMessages",
            "applicationId": "appid...",
            "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
            "clientState": null,
            "notificationUrl": "https://url.com",
            "notificationQueryOptions": null,
            "notificationContentType": "application/json",
            "lifecycleNotificationUrl": null,
            "expirationDateTime": "2021-06-23T08:59:00.0004497Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "44cd97cc-0a17-46a7-b9c0-...",
            "resource": "/teams/getAllMessages",
            "applicationId": "appid...",
            "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
            "clientState": null,
            "notificationUrl": "https://url.com",
            "notificationQueryOptions": null,
            "notificationContentType": "application/json",
            "lifecycleNotificationUrl": null,
            "expirationDateTime": "2021-06-23T09:59:00.0000472Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "ec91353f-6fc5-428a-9145-...",
            "resource": "/teams/getAllMessages",
            "applicationId": "appid...",
            "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
            "clientState": null,
            "notificationUrl": "https://url.com",
            "notificationQueryOptions": null,
            "notificationContentType": "application/json",
            "lifecycleNotificationUrl": null,
            "expirationDateTime": "2021-06-23T18:58:59.9998227Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "64947372-832f-405a-99e5-...",
            "resource": "/teams/getAllMessages",
            "applicationId": "appid...",
            "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
            "clientState": null,
            "notificationUrl": "https://url.com",
            "notificationQueryOptions": null,
            "notificationContentType": "application/json",
            "lifecycleNotificationUrl": null,
            "expirationDateTime": "2021-06-23T22:58:59.9998244Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "62c8d07f-4cc9-4d42-88a1-...",
            "resource": "/teams/getAllMessages",
            "applicationId": "appid...",
            "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
            "clientState": null,
            "notificationUrl": "https://url.com",
            "notificationQueryOptions": null,
            "notificationContentType": "application/json",
            "lifecycleNotificationUrl": null,
            "expirationDateTime": "2021-06-23T03:59:00.0004433Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "83f06882-600d-42b0-8d20-...",
            "resource": "/teams/getAllMessages",
            "applicationId": "appid...",
            "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
            "clientState": null,
            "notificationUrl": "https://url.com",
            "notificationQueryOptions": null,
            "notificationContentType": "application/json",
            "lifecycleNotificationUrl": null,
            "expirationDateTime": "2021-06-24T05:58:59.9995389Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am unable to delete or get the subscription.

```
DELETE /subscriptions/83f06882-600d-42b0-8d20-...
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "Operation: Delete; Exception: [Status Code: NotFound; Reason: NotFound]",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-06-30T03:17:01",
            "request-id": "27496aff-5e3e-4bda-9184-a2f248cef30f",
            "client-request-id": "27496aff-5e3e-4bda-9184-a2f248cef30f"
        }
    }
}

GET /subscriptions/83f06882-600d-42b0-8d20-...
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "There was an error processing a storage extension.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-06-30T03:15:40",
            "request-id": "ba9a3046-6a93-4058-ac22-f83dbc4ceed8",
            "client-request-id": "ba9a3046-6a93-4058-ac22-f83dbc4ceed8"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I remove the expired subscriptions from the list of subscriptions? Thank you!

Updated code to include request-id for the GET/DELETE request.

Comment: How consistent is this issue on your end? I am unable to reproduce this but I think its a temporary issue with the specific tenant. Can you try again and share the request id and timestamp?

Comment: Hi, yes, I am still facing the issue now, not much changes to the list of subscription (apart from having more expired subscriptions). I have updated the post above to include the request ID and timestamp for GET/DELETE request. 
I also do not face such issue with other Tenant, hence I am not sure what configuration has went wrong for this specific Tenant. Thank you!